# Why does Fisher Scoring have linear convergence?

Tags: optimization

It seems that Newton-Raphson is said to have quadratic convergence, and that Fisher Scoring has linear convergence.  By Fisher Scoring, I mean Newton-Raphson, but replace the Hessian with its expectation. That is,
$$\theta_{m+1} = \theta_m + I^{-1}(\theta_m)*V(\theta_m)$$

Where $I(\theta) = \mathbb{E}[J(\theta)]$ is the Fisher Information (the expected Hessian), and $V(\theta)$ is the score.

**What is the proof that Fisher Scoring has linear convergence?**

This is result is claimed in "A generic algorithm for reducing bias in parametric estimation" by Kosmidis and Firth in (2010), and in "Partitioned algorithms for maximum likelihood and other non-linear estimation" by Smyth in (1995). But I don't see reference/theory about this.

Comment: It seems this may be a consequence of Ostrowski's Theorem, as referenced in Proposition 12.2.1 in "Optimization" by K.Lange